# Http service cache

Tags: angular, http, caching, rxjs

I'm trying to implement caching in Angular application for http service.

My code in service **countriesService**

```
  public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/countries`, {})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .publishReplay(1)
      .refCount();
  }
```

In component **CountriesComponent**, I have

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.countriesService.get()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.countries = res.countries;
      });
  }
```

I'm loading component in route config

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'countries', component: CountriesComponent },
  { path: 'cities', component: CitiesComponent },
];
```

Every time I returning from cities to countries, I see a request to => /countries. It shouldn't fire request as it should be cached(that's how it's working in angular 1.x with promises), but not with angular 4 and rxJs.

Comment: could it just because it is called in ngOnInit , hence when you come from cities to countries it fires up again ?

Comment: yeah, I think that's why it happens. But from my experience with ng 1.x and promise $http there shouldn't be requests on further ngOnInit until I clear cache manually or modify request url

Answer (score 13):

you can save countries in service for first time after that you can re use Service variable.

```
 public get(): Observable<any> {

        if(this.countries != null) 
        {
            return Observable.of(this.countries );
        } 
        else 
        {
               return this.http.get(`/countries`, {})
               .map(res => res.json())
               .do(countries => this.countries = countries )
               .publishReplay(1)
                 .refCount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this a common way to handle caching in angular 2-4 with rxjs? Or maybe my whole app composition is wrong?

Comment: if you want cache in service level you can do like this. if you want save app info like user details or permission you can save in browser local storage. your saving couturiers and cites so i think serve cache enough for you.